# linq executecommand

Tags: database, linq-to-sql

Hi when i try to run the .sql script using db.ExecuteCommand, i got this error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'`

My create database statement as below

`IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Users]') AND type in (N'U'))`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users(
[Id]        int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
[RoleId]    int NOT NULL,
[Name]      varchar(50) NOT NULL,
[Gender]    char(1) NULL,
[Status]    int NOT NULL,
```

)

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

I removed the `GO` and it works well. linq executeCommand 'hate' GO :)

Answer (score 1):

Try throwing a `BEGIN` Before "Create Table"  and an `END` After the "Create Table" statement